# What do i need to do after importing aar with File|New|NewModule?

Tags: android, aar

I am trying to use the library `android-simple-storage` from github. Most of the questions about aar files are for AS previous to 1.3 and do not answer this specific question. I downloaded the zip file, unzipped it, and built it with Android Studio. I found the `library-release.aar` file in `library/build/outputs/aar`, renamed it to
`AndroidSimpleStorage.aar`, then imported it into my project using File|New|NewModule.

The problem is that i get "cannot resolve symbol" errors for `Storage` and
`SimpleStorage` in statements such as these two:

```
static Storage storage = null;

storage = SimpleStorage.getExternalStorage();
```

The author has these import statements which work in his test code, but when i
use them i get "cannot resolve symbol" for `sromku`:

```
import com.sromku.simple.storage.SimpleStorage;
import com.sromku.simple.storage.SimpleStorageConfiguration;
import com.sromku.simple.storage.Storage;
import com.sromku.simple.storage.helpers.OrderType;
```

So there is something am missing? Any help appreciated.

Comment: why you do not use remote dependency (`compile` entry in gradle file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, don't forget to compile it into your gradle settings.

You can do this by opening project settings and adding the new module to your app's dependencies tab.

Comment: OK i got it. I went to File|ProjectStructure|app|Dependencies|+ and added in the new module AndroidSimpleStorage. Solved that problem. Thank you, i would never have found that myself.

Comment: Glad to help. Thanks for completing the answer with the specific steps at this time of the sw dev status.