# NoClassDefFoundError after importing aar

Tags: android

I successfuly used https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress according to documentation.

```
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'

<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    custom:donut_finished_stroke_width="4dp"
    custom:donut_unfinished_stroke_width="3dp"
    custom:donut_progress="40"/>
```

But I missed an attribute `donut_circle_starting_degree` that was added to Git but new version has not been released. So I downloaded this library and packaged it myself locally. I used Android studio feature to import a module from aar.

I added this module as compile dependency to my original module. A compilation is OK but it fails at runtime:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/lelisoft.com.lelimath-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/lelisoft.com.lelimath-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:583)
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

I tested other import options without luck. This is similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/32598823/1639556

Comment: 1.1 dependency workw, but 1.2 does not exist. I guess that 1.0 is the first and oldest version, is not it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to clean the library project and the project that import it

Comment: wow, I have rebuilt the project before but cleaning + rebuild made difference. thanks

Comment: you are welcome man very good :) when i face this problem i just clean the project :)

Comment: I had to actually re-download the aar in question. After cleaning didn't help. Turns out the original download had a bad bit or something. In any case check your files too!